# How prove that question

Tags: real-analysis

## Show that

$ \sqrt{20062010201120122013} \notin  \Bbb N$

How do that please

Comment: Show that a square of a whole number never ends in $3$.

Comment: Approximate the square root and show this number is between the squares of the floor and ceiling of the approximation.  Or, show that the prime factorization contains an odd power.  Or...

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the downvote

Comment: The downvoter you are referring to wasn't me, but there are several reasons why the question might have been downvoted.  The title of the question does not give any information as to the question itself (making it less useful to other users searching for similar questions), Spelling errors (e.g. "pleas"$\neq$"please") making it seem like little to no effort was put into crafting the question, Poor tagging (elementary number theory seems more appropriate), and most importantly it is missing context including what efforts you have already made in trying to approach and understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

suppose that it has a natural square root, $n=\sqrt{...}\in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the last digit of the square root.
if it's 1, then the last digit of $n^2$ is 1, which is not true.
if it's 2, then the last digit is 4, which is also not true.
you can go like this on every digit from 1 to 9, and see that there is no proper solution, so that number doesn't have natural square root.